# Service returning unexpected result, promise ignored

Tags: angularjs

The service is returning `data` (the raw $http response) rather than `result` (the processed version I want to pass back to my controller), why is the code inside `promise` being ignored?

```
///in controller
Romanize.get($scope.currentMaterial).then(function(d){
    $scope.romanized = d;
});

//service
app.factory('Romanize', ['$http', 'Position', function($http, Position){
    return{
      get: function(query){
            var url= Position.sections[Position.sectionNumber].romanizeService + "?korean=" + query;
            var promise = $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                var parts = $(data).find("span");
                var array = [];
                for (var x = 0; x<parts.length; x++){
                    array.push(parts[x].title);
                }
                var result = array.join("");
                return result;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`success` handler does not provide chain. You should use `then`:

```js
var promise = $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
  var parts = $(data).find("span");
  // ...
  return result;
});
```

Comment: I thought success was a callback to be called up successful http 200 status. What use is it then?